# Как скрыть признаки использования YII2?

Tags: php, yii

Возможно ли скрыть признаки использования фреймворка YII2 в wappalyzer и других подобных расширениях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, конечно.
Для начала вам необходимо узнать как конкретно эти расширения узнают тот или иной фреймворк. К примеру, указанный вами [wappalyzer](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer) описывает yii следующим образом:

```
    "Yii": {
        "cats": [
            "18"
        ],
        "env": "^yii$",
        "html": [
            "Powered by <a href=\"http://www\\.yiiframework\\.com/\" rel=\"external\">Yii Framework</a>",
            "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}\" name=\"YII_CSRF_TOKEN\" \\/>",
            "<!\\[CDATA\\[YII-BLOCK-(?:HEAD|BODY-BEGIN|BODY-END)\\]"
        ],
        "script": "yii.*\\.js",
        "icon": "Yii.png",
        "implies": [
            "PHP"
        ],
        "website": "http://yiiframework.com"
    },
```

взят [отсюда](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json).
Описание каждого поля есть в [документации](https://www.wappalyzer.com/docs/specification).

Из написанного выше, понятно, что как минимум надо:

1. скрыть js с названием yii.js
2. переименовать csrf_token
3. убрать надпись powered by yii framework
4. Убрать или переименовать глобальную js переменную yii(пункт env)

Возможно проще убрать ответ сервера о том, что используется PHP.

Все это конечно верно исключительно для одного инструмента, и только для текущей версии.

Comment: еще иконку сменить)) ......`скрыть js с названием yii.js` - кто вообще использует `yii.js` для скриптов?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [это часть фреймворка](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#yii.js), [вот пример сценария](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294139/delete-button-with-confirmation-in-yii2/44301019#44301019), а [вот сам файл](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.js)